# npm search is not to work.Why?

Tags: npm

Want to know npm search is not going to the official website to find a package? If so , why my npm search query seems to be set up in the local index , the results did not find.Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

The npm repo is the official site to find node modules.
If you don't get the results that you want you can always use other alternative search sites like:

- http://search.node.modules.by.locoticket.com  (this is the best by
  far)
- http://nipstr.com/